# React/Node.js - API Call to Generate then Display PDF

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, create-react-app

I'm having trouble with displaying dynamically generated PDFs on a React frontend. I'm able to generate and make the PDF available for download, but the creation/placement of it into my client-side directory is causing issues where the updated state of the app is repeatedly refreshing. The app has users write a text input, analyzes it and pulls up a list of possible images from an API based on the text, then lets the user select which images they want and packages them into a pdf for downloading.

I'm working in a MERN stack with the create-react-app boilerplate serving a frontend application nested inside of a Node.js API directory. For the PDFs I'm using `pdfkit` to generate the PDFs on the backend and `react-pdf` to render them on the frontend. My file structure looks like this:

```
client
  --public
    --pdfs
      --<generated pdf saved here>
  --src
    --components
      --Root.js
      --ImageSelect.js
      --ImageDownload.js
      --PDFDisplay.js
controller
  --<controller receiving API call and calling model functions/returning JSON to frontend here>
model
  --<model generating PDF & saving it here>
```

The process starts on a form submit in `ImageSelect.js` where I'm doing a bit of data manipulation and then making the API call to create the PDF before redirecting to `ImageDownload`:

```
    const config = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        script: this.state.indexedScript,
        versions: versionSubmit
      })
    };
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_URL + "/api/getFinalizedImages", config)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.props.handleImageSelect(this.state.indexedScript, versionSubmit, json.pdfLink))
    .then(this.props.history.push("/imageDownload"));
```

The original user input text, selected pictures that make up the PDF, and the PDF filename are all passed to the `Root.js` router so that they can then be made available to `ImageDownload.js`

```
handleImageSelect = (indexedScript, versionSubmit, pdfLink) => {
    this.setState({
      indexedScript: indexedScript,
      versionSubmit: versionSubmit,
      pdfLink: pdfLink
    });
  }

    render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <... Other Routes Here...>
          <Route path='/imageSelect' render={(props) => (
            <ImageSelect {...props} script={this.state.submittedScript} 
            handleImageSelect={this.handleImageSelect} />
          )}/>
          <Route path='/imageDownload' render={(props) => (
            <ImageDownload {...props} indexedScript={this.state.indexedScript}
            versions={this.state.versionSubmit} pdfLink={this.state.pdfLink} />
          )}/>          
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

Finally, in `ImageDownload.js` I'm hoping to receive the dynamically-generated PDF filename from the routing component and pass it to the `PDFDisplay.js` component for rendering:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;

class PDFDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numPages: null,
      pageNumber: 1
    }
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages } = this.state;
    const filePath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/client/pdfs/' + this.props.pdf + '.pdf';
    return (
      <div>
        <Document
          file={filePath}
          onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
        </Document>
        <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PDFDisplay;
```

The issue at present is that `ImageDownload` view is refreshed several times when the PDF creation form is submitted in `ImageSelect`; when it is done refreshing none of the props are passed through. I've tried a variety of other approaches like putting the API call into `ImageDownload`'s `componentDidMount` (refresh triggered another API call which meant endless refreshes/generated PDFs) and saving the PDF in a backend directory (frontend couldn't access a file outside of its directory for display), so I'm not sure what approach I should be taking here.